# Get the last 4 characters of a string as long as they are special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have web URLs that look like this:

```
http://example.com/php?id=2/*
http://example.com/php?id=2'
http://example.com/php?id=2*/"
```

What I need to do is grab the last characters of the string, I've tried:

```
for urls in html_page:
    syntax = list(url)[-1]
# <= *
# <= '
# etc...
```

However this will only grab the last character of the string, is there a way I could grab the last characters as long as they are special characters?

Comment: Yes. Read up on regular expressions. Your question shows very little research effort on your part.

Comment: 1. define "special characters" 2. you can write a function that iterates a string from the end back and stops when it reaches a "not special" character

Comment: What's the expected output for each case, don't you just want to get the value of `id`?

Comment: What are special characters exactly? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression?

```
import re
addr = "http://example.com/php?id=2*/"
chars = re.search(addr, "[\*\./_]{0,4}$").group()
```

Characters you want to match are the ones between the `[]` brackets. You may want to add or remove characters depending on what you expect to encounter.
For example, you would (probably) not want to match the `'='` character in your example URLs, which the other answer would match.
`{0,4}` means to match 0-4 characters (defaults to being greedy)

Comment: How would I capture a `"`?

Comment: `'\"'`  or to add it to the regex above: `"[\"\*\./_]{0,4}$"`

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex. Assuming that by "special character" you mean "anything besides `A-Za-z0-9`":

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"\W+$", "http://example.com/php?id=2*/'").group()
"*/'"
```

`\W+` matches one or more "non-word" characters, and `$` anchors the search to the end of the string.